# How to execute a Group Collection Query using Firestore? (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey everybody this is my first time asking a question on here so if the posting is incorrect etc... i apologize in advance. 
I'm working on a project where students at the university I go to will be able to request a Resident Advisor to unlock their rooms for them. I'm stuck on how to query the entire(root) collection to find a  subcollection with a field that contains a value that matches my collection ID. I've seen a lot of resources on Stack, Firebase, and i've tried to implement them but I've had no succes.

Here's a picture:

[Accessing the Subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQN3.png)

My code snippet is:

```
db.collectionGroup("Dorms").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: UID).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in    

// here is where i'd like to gather the fields subcollection/document and then store them as variables
```

Thank you in advance for any help and advice. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried anything yet.  The documentation is fairly clear about what to do next.  (By the way, if you're using a Firebase Auth UID as the name of a collection, I would advise against that. You will have problems later.)

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo or not but your query is `.whereField("UID", isEqualTo: "UID")` so you are querying for all UID fields that have a *value* of the string "UID". Is that what you mean to do as the UID showing in the linked screenshot is "LWKVL8...". Also, please don't use links in questions - add the actual image. Links can break over time and if that happens, future readers won't know what your structure is.

Comment: @DougStevenson There were different solutions i had tried, but i decided to delete what hadn't worked for me before i posted my code snippet. I'm curious though what would be a better to identify my specific user collections instead of using the FIrebase Auth UID?

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry that was a typo. .whereField("UID", isEqualTo: "UID") is supposed to be s .whereField("UID", isEqualTo: UID).  UID represents the variable of a logged in user's current uid. So when a new user logs in, the view controller will get that user's uid instead of a preset uid value. I'll make sure to also add the actual image next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first time posting an answer so I hope this is somewhat helpful, but in my experience when querying files in a collection I create a `forloop` then use if let statements to get variables from the document

```
var someVariable : Int


db.collectionGroup("Dorms").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: "UID").getDocuments { (snapshot,  error) in
        if let e = error {
            //this is printing the error if there is one getting the documents
            print("There was an error getting the documents \(e)")
        } else {
            if let dorms = snapshot?.documents { //accesses all the documents in the collection
                for doc in dorms {
                    let data = doc.data() //Gets all the information in the document
                    //Here you would use an if let to create variables from the information in the data
                    //For example
                    if let dormRoomNumber = data["dormRoomNumber"]/*You'll put the name of your field in here, so whatever you have named it in firestore*/] as? Int //make sure the the data type here mathces the data type in your firestore database
                    {
                        someVariable = dormRoomNumber
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Instead of all of those if statements, Firestore documentSnapshot has a `.get.` function that will read the field by name. If you combine that with a nil-coelecsing operator, it may save you some typing.  So replace the entire if statement with `let dormRoomNumber = doc.get("dormRoomNumber") as? String ?? "No number available"`

Comment: I agree that would save space, my preference is the if because when querying Firestone, things will generally need to be reloaded and I like to do that in the if statement. For example if you had a table view present after getting the information you would need to reload tableview data and I like to do that within the if block if an I need to. I guess what I'm saying is, is that if you don't need to do any extra manipulation to the variable or reload things once you have the information than the nil-coalescing operator is a great choice too. I hope that helped.

Comment: @shant_01 Thank you! I am new to working with Firestore and there is a lot i'm still figuring out. Your solution now has that part of my code working as i need it to!